# Javascript multi-dimension array initialization

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm looking for the best way to initialize multi-dimensional arrays in Javascript. I'm much more familiar with PHP where I'm not obliged to declare arrays or dimensions before feeding it with values.

Basically what I tried to do is create an array with the following format

```
catalogue[i]["name"]="a name";
catalogue[i]["description"]="a description";
```

...etc...

If I do the following:

```
var catalogue = new Array();
for (i=0; i<otherarray.length;i++)
    {
       catalogue[i]['name']=otherarray[i];
    }
```

Catalogue is undefined, I also tried with catalogue[i].name but same issue. If I only assign a simple value like catalogue[i]=2, it works but that's not what I'm looking for. I couldn't find a working example of what I'm looking for.

Do I need to initialize every possible dimension of an array before being able to feed it with new values?

Thanks
Laurent

Comment: Note that arrays don't have keys in javascript, only numeric indexes, so what you really want to create is an object.

Comment: use an object not an array .

Comment: `catalogue` isn’t undefined, `catalogue[i]` is. You can sill write `catalogue[i] = {};` right before `catalogue[i]['name'] = otherarray[i];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your loop to create the object you want to store the values in:

`catalogue[i] = {};` OR `catalogue.push({});`

Your code would be like this then:

```
var catalogue = new Array();
for (i=0; i<otherarray.length;i++)
{
   catalogue[i] = {}; // initialization
   catalogue[i]['name']=otherarray[i];
}
```

Note that you can initialize and assign a value in the same line:

```
var catalogue = new Array();
for (i=0; i<otherarray.length;i++)
{
    catalogue[i] = {
        name: otherarray[i],
        otherKey: 'otherValue' // list all of your keys and values
    };
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
var catalogue = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < otherarray.length; i++) {
  catalogue[i] = {};
  catalogue[i]['name'] = otherarray[i];
}
```

Or

```
var catalogue = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < otherarray.length; i++) {
  catalogue.push({"name":otherarray[i]});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want string keys in your array in Javascript you have to declare an Object. The `catalogue` variable itself is an array but each element inside that array is an object with the two keys "name" and "description". For example this code works :

```
var c = [1,2,3,4,5];
var n = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
var cat = [];
for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
{
  cat[i] = {
    name : n[i],
    value: c[i]
  };
}
```

now if you `console.dir(cat);` it outputs this result :

```
Array[5]
    -> 0 : Object
        name: "one"
        value: 1
    -> 1 : Object
        name: "two"
        value: 2
    ...
```